# iOS : Application Loader gives 1069618639.itmsp error and java.heap.space exception

Tags: ios, xcode6, application-loader

I am facing an issue while uploading iPA on test-flight via Application Loader and Xcode. How to resolve this?

I am using **Xcode v6.4** and Application Loader v3.1

**Errors as follows :**

1. Error while processing package 1069618639.itmsp
2. An exception has occurred: Java heap space

[image]

Please refer attached screenshot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: update jdk to the latest version!

Comment: @Anilsolanki, Bad luck. It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with OsX 10.9.5 and Xcode 6.2. Resolved, after few days of try, only updating my Mac to El Capitain and last version of Xcode. I suppose was an incompatibility with java and/or with multitasking config not available on old Xcode.

Comment: solved it for me. we now use XCode 7.2.1 and Application Loader 3.4