# How to deal with "error while processing package 1027656484.itmsp . An exception has occurred : Java heap space"

Tags: java, heap-memory

How to deal with

> "error while processing package 1027656484.itmsp .  An exception has occurred : Java heap space".

I'm trying upload my app to Apple store.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue. I am facing same problem :(

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35060267/1075628 . He suggests updating of OSX and XCode, this solved it for some user although his answer is not yet marked as solution by the original requestor.